# Equation alignment between columns

Tags: horizontal-alignment, columns, fractions

I don't really know how to ask this but I want my fraction bar to be aligned between columns and that the letter (for example b and c) to be also aligned. Is that possible?

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \noindent

        $\dfrac{1-e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}=\frac{1-\dfrac{1}{e^x}}{1+\dfrac{1}{e^x}}=\dfrac{e^x-1}{e^x+1}$

    \columnbreak
    \noindent
    $\dfrac{e^x-1}{e^{2x}}=\dfrac{e^x}{e^{2x}}-\dfrac{1}{e^{2x}}=e^{-x}-e^{-2x}$
\end{multicols}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

```
\begin{multicols}{4}
    \noindent

        $a = e^{2x} \times e^{-2x}\\
        a = e^{2x-2x}\\
        a = e^0\\
        a=1$

    \columnbreak 
    \noindent

    $b=e^{2x+1}\times e^{1-x}\\
    b=e^{2x+1+1-x}\\
    b=e^{x+2}\\$

    \columnbreak 
    \noindent

    $c=\dfrac{e^{x+2}}{e^{-x+2}}\\
    c=e^{x+2+x-2}\\
    c=e^{2x}$

    \columnbreak
    \noindent

    $d=\dfrac{e^{3x}+e^x}{e^{2x}+1}\\
    d=\dfrac{e^x(e^{2x}+1)}{e^{2x}+1}\\
    d=e^x$\\
\end{multicols}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

I'm sorry I'm new to this website.

Comment: `multicols` is really intended for balancing columns of text not for displaying things in fixed column alignment, it would be better to use a table for that. Also the math markup here is very strange why using inline math `$` but then using display fractions with `\dfrac` and `\\ ` breaks rather than use a multi-line math display environment such as `align` ?

Comment: Thank you I'll try that. I used the multicols because I didn't really know about the align environnement. I just started yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

I would use something like:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}*{4}{p{2.6cm}}@{}}
{\begin{align*}
    a &= e^{2x} \times e^{-2x}\\
    a &= e^{2x-2x}\\
    a &= e^0\\
    a&=1
\end{align*}}
&
{\begin{align*}
b&=e^{2x+1}\times e^{1-x}\\
b&=e^{2x+1+1-x}\\
b&=e^{x+2}
\end{align*}}
&
{\begin{align*}
c&=\dfrac{e^{x+2}}{e^{-x+2}}\\
c&=e^{x+2+x-2}\\
c&=e^{2x}
\end{align*}}
&
{\begin{align*}
d&=\dfrac{e^{3x}+e^x}{e^{2x}+1}\\
d&=\dfrac{e^x(e^{2x}+1)}{e^{2x}+1}\\
d&=e^x
\end{align*}}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

or if you want ever row as a separate row:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    a &= e^{2x} \times e^{-2x} &
b&=e^{2x+1}\times e^{1-x}&
c&=\dfrac{e^{x+2}}{e^{-x+2}}&
d&=\dfrac{e^{3x}+e^x}{e^{2x}+1}
\\
    a &= e^{2x-2x}&
b&=e^{2x+1+1-x}&
c&=e^{x+2+x-2}&
d&=\dfrac{e^x(e^{2x}+1)}{e^{2x}+1}
\\
    a &= e^0&
b&=e^{x+2}&
c&=e^{2x}&
d&=e^x\\
 a&=1
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But then as you can see the b= and the c= are not aligned.

Comment: @Hyraeth it wasn't clear what you wanted, the b= are  aligned with each other. If you want each row to be a row, then you just need to restructure and put all the first rows in the first row of the outer tabular then all the second rows in the second row of the tabular, etc. I'll add that version

Comment: Thank you ! I'm sorry I wasn't really clear about what I whanted when I posted my question. I think I understand now. I started LaTeX yesterday so my knowlegde about the differents environments isn't that great.

Comment: @Hyraeth I added a second version. started yesterday, not bad for a first day! ( (I started last century-)

Comment: I put a new version with the simplest markup just using a single `align` environment.

Comment: Thank you very much that's exactly how I wanted it to be! Also yes it's not that bad but it could be better, I think I should have learned a bit more before starting.

Answer (score 0):

For maximum flexibility, while maintaining the ability to align the equations both horizontally and vertically, consider using four top-aligned `array` environments placed inside four top-aligned `minipage` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % no other packages required
\newcommand\bigstrut{\vphantom{\frac{e^{3x}+e^x}{e^{2x}+1}}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\displaystyle\bigstrut}l}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{2.25}
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
\centering
$\begin{array}[t]{L@{{}={}}L}
        a & e^{2x} \times e^{-2x}\\
          & e^{2x-2x}\\
          & e^0\\
          &1
\end{array}$
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
\centering
$\begin{array}[t]{L@{{}={}}L}
    b&e^{2x+1}\times e^{1-x}\\
     &e^{2x+1+1-x}\\
     &e^{x+2}
\end{array}$
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
\centering
$\begin{array}[t]{L@{{}={}}L}
    c&\frac{e^{x+2}}{e^{-x+2}}\\
     &e^{x+2+x-2}\\
     &e^{2x}
\end{array}$
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
\centering
$\begin{array}[t]{L@{{}={}}L}
    d&\frac{e^{3x}+e^x}{e^{2x}+1}\\
     &\frac{e^x(e^{2x}+1)}{e^{2x}+1}\\
     &e^x
\end{array}$
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want independent rows in each column, a simple solution comes with the `tasks` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}[label = {\relax}, label-width = 0pt](4)
\task $ \begin{aligned}[t]
    a &= e^{2x} \times e^{-2x}\\
    a &= e^{2x-2x}\\
    a &= e^0\\
    a&=1
\end{aligned} $

\task $ \begin{aligned}[t]
b&=e^{2x+1}\times e^{1-x}\\
b&=e^{2x+1+1-x}\\
b&=e^{x+2}
\end{aligned} $

\task
$ \begin{aligned}[t]
c&=\dfrac{e^{x+2}}{e^{-x+2}}\\
c&=e^{x+2+x-2}\\
c&=e^{2x}
\end{aligned}$

\task
$ \begin{aligned}[t]
d&=\dfrac{e^{3x}+e^x}{e^{2x}+1}\\
d&=\dfrac{e^x(e^{2x}+1)}{e^{2x}+1}\\
d&=e^x
\end{aligned} $

\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]